# JsonLayout and variables

Tags: c#, nlog

I try to create a JsonLayout programmatically and use variables. But the variable values are not rendered because my JsonLayout object's LoggingConfiguration = null.

Since LoggingConfiguration is in the base class Layout and has a private setter, I can not specify it in my JsonLayout instance except in the Immediate window.

Example:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["myVariable"] = "myVariableValue";
var jsonLayout = new JsonLayout
{
    Attributes =
    {
        new JsonAttribute("@timestamp", "${longdate}"),
        new JsonAttribute("level", "${level}"),
        new JsonAttribute("variable", "${var:myVariable}"),
    },
    IncludeEventProperties = true,
    IncludeGdc = true,
    IncludeScopeProperties = true
};

var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, "myLogger", "myMessage");
var layoutValue = jsonLayout.Render(logEventInfo);

//Actual
//{ "@timestamp": "2022-06-28 10:38:39.1820", "level": "Error" }

//If I set the internal LoggingConfiguration in the Immediate window
//jsonLayout.LoggingConfiguration = LogManager.Configuration;

//I get the expected result
//layoutValue = jsonLayout.Render(logEventInfo);
//{ "@timestamp": "2022-06-28 10:39:14.6181", "level": "Error", "variable": "myVariableValue" }
```

I need to do this in code but how do I get the LoggerConfiguration reference into my jsonLayout object?
Can I initiate my JsonLayout in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the JsonLayout to the Configuration.

E.g.

```cs
var config = LogManager.Configuration;
config Variables["myVariable"] = "myVariableValue";

var jsonLayout = new JsonLayout
{
    Attributes =
    {
        new JsonAttribute("@timestamp", "${longdate}"),
        new JsonAttribute("level", "${level}"),
        new JsonAttribute("variable", "${var:myVariable}"),
    },
    IncludeEventProperties = true,
    IncludeGdc = true,
    IncludeScopeProperties = true
};

config.AddTarget(jsonLayout); // add target
LogManager.Configuration = config; // apply
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot AddTarget because of: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NLog.Layouts.JsonLayout' to 'NLog.Targets.Target'. Is there any other way I should go?